# Загрузка изображений на сервер с помощью Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, retrofit, alamofire

Возникла следующая проблема, дело в том, что иногда не выгружаются изображения на сервер. Все данные корректны, изображение присутствует, переменные расставлены в правильном порядке, функция сообщает о успешной выгрузке, но изображения на сервер иногда все равно не доходят. С библиотекой Retorfit таких проблем нет, а вот с Alamofire часто возникает. Не могу пока разобраться почему.

```
class func write_photo(params:[String:String],image:UIImage, in_position:String, completion:_ js:String, _ success:Bool -> Void, failure:_ errorMessage:String,_ failure:Bool -> Void) {
let url = BaseURL + "xdb_items.write_photo"
let URL = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post)
let in_idclient = params["in_idclient"]
let in_iditem = params["in_iditem"]
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
sessionManagerImage.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
multipartFormData.append((in_idclient?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: "in_idclient")
multipartFormData.append((in_iditem?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: "in_iditem")
multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "in_filename", fileName: "photo", mimeType: "image/png")
multipartFormData.append((in_position.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!), withName: "in_position")
}, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
encodingResult in
switch encodingResult {
case .success(let upload, _, _):
upload.response { response in
completion("", true)
}
case .failure(let encodingError):
print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
}
})
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: Никакой, но случайно делал отладку и там появилось следующие предупреждение: **could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. at real iPhone device**, на поле in_iditem, может быть проблема в этом, но как её решить?

Comment: Проблема не в этом. Если не возникает никаких ошибок, но изображение иногда не доходит до сервера, значит проблема на сервере.

Comment: Тогда почему на Android, библиотека Retrofit, таких проблем не возникает?

Comment: нашел ошибку, status code 500, из-за чего она может возникать?

Comment: 500 это внутренняя ошибка сервера. Проще говоря, косяк в коде. Стоит посмотреть логи сервера. Сервер на чем написан?

Comment: На PL SQL, сервак на Oracle. А где можно посмотреть логи сервера?

Comment: Тут я ничего не могу посоветовать, с Oracle не работал. Ищите доступ к логам сервера.

Comment: Но в голове не укладывается, почему все работает на Androide.

Comment: Может быть множество причин. Например в Android библиотеке в запросе неявно указывается какой-нибудь параметр, а в iOS нет.